# Citrus version and Cucumber version issue

Tags: citrus-framework

Citrus 2.7.7 is not compatible with cucumber 3.0.2 or later and when I check the sample from GitHub, they are using 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT with cucumber 3.0.2. So when is the 2.8.0 release version will be out?  For me, I am able to get the 2.8.0-SNAPSHOT without any issue. But for some of my colleague they are not able to get it even with this.

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>consol-labs-snapshots</id>
      <url>http://labs.consol.de/maven/snapshots-repository/</url>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>interval:10080</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
```

Answer (score 0):

We're planning to release 2.8.0 no later than by the end of the year. Stay tuned on [twitter](https://twitter.com/citrus_test) or on http://citrusframework.org/.

The maven config seems to be okay so far. Could you provide some information about the error message?

Edit:
Have your tried the `-U` flag for maven? E.g. `mvn clean install -U` to force updates on snapshots?

BR,
Sven

Answer (score 0):

@Sven Hettwer,

There is no error message, it just says not able to find the artifact!